# What is custom SVM kernel?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, machine-learning-model, svm, kernel

What is custom kernel in the Support Vector Machine. How is it different from Polynomial kernel. How to implement a custom kernel. Can you provide a code to implement a custom kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Custom Kernel can be any user defined function which transforms the training set of data so that non linear boundaries can be transformed to linear boundaries in higher dimensions.

Polynomial kernel is just one type of kernel we also of RBF, Sigmoid,Linear, Gaussian and other kernels. Every Kernel has some property.

Polynomial Kernel: It represents the similarity of vectors in the training set of data in a feature space over polynomials of the original variables used in the kernel.

Code for Custom Kernel can be found in skicit learn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_custom_kernel.html) :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm, datasets

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features. We could
# avoid this ugly slicing by using a two-dim dataset
Y = iris.target


def my_kernel(X, Y):
    """
    We create a custom kernel:

                 (2  0)
    k(X, Y) = X  (    ) Y.T
                 (0  1)
    """
    M = np.array([[2, 0], [0, 1.0]])
    return np.dot(np.dot(X, M), Y.T)


h = 0.02  # step size in the mesh

# we create an instance of SVM and fit out data.
clf = svm.SVC(kernel=my_kernel)
clf.fit(X, Y)

# Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
# point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)

# Plot also the training points
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=Y, cmap=plt.cm.Paired, edgecolors="k")
plt.title("3-Class classification using Support Vector Machine with custom kernel")
plt.axis("tight")
plt.show()
```